# Are there such things as destructors in Swift?

Tags: swift

Are there reserved keywords for destructors in Swift?  Is there even a need for such a thing in this language?

Answer (score 24):

> Are there reserved keywords for destructors in Swift?

[`deinit` (Deinitialization)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Deinitialization.html) handles cleanup which should occur before the object is released.

> Is there even a need for such a thing in this language?

There are a few standard things done in `deinit`. Remove observers, synchronize the state of an object, and write trace messages for debugging. Other things are possible, just avoid long running chunks of code.

Comment: I would like to put `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` in `init()` and `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(false)` in `deinit()`. Is that ok? or bad idea?(trying to create my own Audio recorder and player)

Comment: @HassanTareq No, it mixes up the lifecycle of an object with a user interface thing. You might need to have `deinit()` call `setActive(false)`, but don't have it be the primary way to `setActive(false)`.

Comment: I created `HoverAudioController` (recorder and player) and using it inside `AudioMessageViewController`. Instantiating `HoverAudioController` in `ViewDidLoad()`. Using `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)` in `HoverAudioController.init()`. I would like to keep session active as long as `AudioMessageViewController` is using `HoverAudioController` and deactivate audio session (`setActive(false)`) when my `HoverAudioController` is garbage collected (i.e. no longer used by `AudioMessageViewController`). currently using `HoverAudioController.deinit{setActive(false)}`. What should I do?

Comment: @HassanTareq That seems reasonable as long as `HoverAudioController` only manages `AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()`. Make sure that no others object save a reference to `HoverAudioController`.